# Indentation Markers with CodeMirror

Tags: codemirror

I'm trying to add indentation markers for CodeMirror. You can see below an example of this being accomplished in the RAML editor ( which uses codemirror ).

[image: raml]

Taking a look at the code there is a `cm-indent` class added thats applying this style:

[image: code]

I've searched through the code base looking for this css class and the docs but don't see a plugin for this capability.

There is a [rulers](https://codemirror.net/demo/rulers.html) plugin that allows you to add markers vertically but these don't align with indentions like the example above.

Does anyone know if something is out there to accomplish this?