# How to get indentation lines in Jupyter Lab/Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

[image]

How can I add Indentation lines like what is shown above in Jupyter Lab/Notebook?

I have tried a lot and went into the settings (not much as I am a beginner and I don't know most of the stuff) but in Jupyter I can only get code numbers from the View button but not these beautiful lines which help a lot when doing the indentation.

Comment: What editor/IDE is the image from with these lines?

Comment: It's replit, I use it to share output codes with my friends.

Answer (score 2):

The default editor used by Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab (CodeMirror) does not support indentation markers as for today; it is possible to extend it with an add-on but it seems that there isn't one yet (see [Indentation Markers with CodeMirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941586/indentation-markers-with-codemirror)). I imagine that you would need to create a custom overlay mode to make it work, and it might be in scope for jupyterlab-lsp extension if you would like to suggest this via issue on GitHub.

JupyterLab also allows to use a different editor via extension (and there was a proof-of-concept for that) but I don't think that anyone volunteered to maintain any other editor integration recently.

In the near future JupyterLab will likely migrate CodeMirror 6, and depending on availability of such feature in it it will either have a support for it or not. Or maybe someone will contribute a support for it to an extension. It might turn out to be easier to implement in CM6.

Comment: Oh! So we just have to wait for JupyterLab to migrate to CM6. Also where can I find the jupyterlab-isp extension, if that helps to solve the problem as of now?

Comment: raised indentation lines during today's jupyterlab meeting

Comment: I guess there are still no updates, right?  (nothing available on notebook 6.4.12, afaics)

Comment: CodeMirror 6 is coming in Notebook 7. Then someone would need to make a PR for example adding https://github.com/replit/codemirror-indentation-markers or making an extension which adds it (which will be easier in Notebook 7/Lab 4).

Answer (score 1):

#### 2024 Update

This has recently become possible through the fresh [jupyterlab-indent-guides](https://github.com/firai/jupyterlab-indent-guides) plugin by user [firai](https://github.com/firai) on GitHub.

It works well: [image]

You can install it via the extension manager in JupyterLab or through pip:

```
pip install jupyterlab-indent-guides
```

If you're on Windows an encounter permission errors whilst using JupyterLab's extension manager this post might help you: [Win10 Jupyter Lab Extension Installation Throws Permission Error [Errno 13]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77964421/6118556)