# Win10 Jupyter Lab Extension Installation Throws Permission Error [Errno 13]

Tags: jupyter-lab

#### Background

I have recently installed Jupyter Lab through conda-forge on my Windows 10 machine.

#### Problem

Whenever I try to install any extensions from within Jupyter Lab, I get this error:

```
Error: ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\MY_USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpm9gfttp2'
```

[image: Screenshot of problem]

#### Question

How can I resolve the problem? I've tried running Anaconda Prompt with admin privileges but that did not change anything. Admin rights should not be required anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Shutdown JupyterLab
2. Simply install the required package outside of JupyterLab using `pip`, like so (this will [force Python to use the pip that is local to the current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment/56889729#56889729)).

```
python -m pip install <package-name>
```

3. The extension will be available for use next time JupyterLab is launched.